# Formal Way to Prove limit without operating on infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

What is the "formal" way of proving 
Limit as x approaches negative infinity of f(x)
Where f(x) = sqrt(5-x)

I know it's positive infinity but in order to get that I had to "operate" on infinity which is not allowed. Is there a different way to do this problem such that operating on infinity does not occur?

Comment: Since "the limit is $+\infty$" we must show that for a given $M>0$ there exist $N>0$ such that when $x<-N$ we have $\sqrt{5-x}>M$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that for any $M>0,$ there is an $N_M<0$ such that for $x<N_M$ we have $f(x)>M.$

This is the (usual) definition of $f(x)$ increasing without bound as $x$ decreases without bound.

Note that "infinity" never came up. The symbol $\infty$ is in large part just notational shorthand for unboundedness.